# Add scrollbar to non-header rows in angular

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I have following code for table in angular. I want a vertical scroll bar only for table body (table rows excluding header) how can I do that?

Since All rows are generated by ng-repeat. I don't know how to add overflow style.

Adding additional div to wrap all non header rows break the table layout and all rows appear in first column.

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10741/

```
    <div class="nu-table">
        <div class="nu-table-row nu-header">
            <div class="nu-table-cell">A</div>
            <div class="nu-table-cell">B</div>
            <div class="nu-table-cell">C</div>
        </div>
        <div class="nu-table-row nu-striped pointer-cursor" ng-repeat=" map in mapList">
            <div class="nu-table-cell"  ng-bind="map.A"></div>
            <div class="nu-table-cell">{{map.B}}</div>
            <div class="nu-table-cell" ng-bind="map.C"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try again to wrap them all into `<div style="display: table-row-group">`

This according to [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) will behave like `<tbody>` and you can add a scrollbar there.

Of course, style must be moved to your Stylesheet